In twilio after conversion of simple call to conference , initial user gets droped
   
    public function createConferenceFromOngoingCall($callSid, $newParticipant, $initialUser, $secondUser)
    {
        try {
            $client = $this->createClient();
            $newParticipantSid = $newParticipant->twilio_worker_sid;
            $conferenceName = 'conf_' . uniqid();
    
            Log::info("Initiating conference creation", [
                'conferenceName' => $conferenceName,
                'originalCallSid' => $callSid,
                'newParticipantSid' => $newParticipantSid,
            ]);
    
            // Create a new conference
            $conferenceTwiML = $this->generateConferenceTwiML($conferenceName);
    
            // Update the existing call with conference TwiML
            $updatedCall = $client->calls($callSid)->update([
                'twiml' => $conferenceTwiML,
                'statusCallback' => url('/twilio/call-status'),
                'statusCallbackEvent' => ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'],
                'statusCallbackMethod' => 'POST',
            ]);
    
            Log::info("Original call updated to join conference", [
                'callSid' => $callSid,
                'status' => $updatedCall->status,
            ]);
    
            // Create a new call for the new participant and add them to the conference
            $newParticipantCall = $client->calls->create(
                'client:' . $newParticipantSid,
                config('services.twilio.number'),
                [
                    'twiml' => $conferenceTwiML,
                    'statusCallback' => url('/twilio/call-status'),
                    'statusCallbackEvent' => ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'],
                    'statusCallbackMethod' => 'POST',
                ]
            );
    
            Log::info("New participant call created", [
                'newParticipantCallSid' => $newParticipantCall->sid,
                'status' => $newParticipantCall->status,
            ]);
    
            // Wait for the conference to be fully established
            $conference = $this->waitForConference($client, $conferenceName);
    
            if ($conference) {
                Log::info("Conference fully established", [
                    'conferenceSid' => $conference->sid,
                    'status' => $conference->status,
                ]);
    
                // Fetch participants
                $participants = $client->conferences($conference->sid)->participants->read();
                Log::info("Conference participants", [
                    'count' => count($participants),
                    'participantSids' => array_map(function($p) { return $p->callSid; }, $participants),
                ]);
            } else {
                Log::warning("Conference not found or not in-progress");
            }
    
            $result = [
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'Conference initiated successfully',
                'conferenceName' => $conferenceName,
                'originalCallSid' => $callSid,
                'newParticipantCallSid' => $newParticipantCall->sid,
                'conferenceSid' => $conference ? $conference->sid : null,
            ];
    
            Log::info("Conference creation result", $result);
    
            return $result;
    
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Failed to create conference from ongoing call: ' . $e->getMessage(), [
                'callSid' => $callSid,
                'newParticipantSid' => $newParticipantSid ?? null,
                'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString(),
            ]);
            return [
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'An error occurred while creating the conference: ' . $e->getMessage(),
            ];
        }
    }
    

THis is how I am trying to convert normal incoming call to conference and add another participant to it , making it conference for 3 people.here the senerio is of type A calls to B , B calls to C, When call is converted to conference A automatically gets drop making participant of the call count to be only 1. I dont understand what is happening and how to stop A to be dropped
I want the solution where A should not be dropped from conference
